# italic(vs) inside subtitle as part of user function

Tags: r, ggplot2

I wrote a function to create repetitive plots using ggplot2.
in the subtitle line, I want the word "vs" will be italic.
my line in code is:

```
labs(
  title=GeneID,subtitle = paste(Geno,expression(italic("vs")),Geno2),
  x="Days post inoculation",
  y="Average relative transcript level"
)
```

It is not working.

`GeneID`, `Geno`, `Geno2` are variables inside the function and must stay like this.

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Edit: the expression solution was not giving the right solution, this works.

```
dt <- data.frame(x <- 1:5, y <- 3:7)

varA <- "FOO"
varB <- "BOO"

ggplot(dt, aes(x, y)) + geom_point() +
  labs(subtitle = substitute(
    ~varA ~italic(vs) ~varB,
    list(varA = varA, varB = varB, vs = "vs")
  )
)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, I tried: subtitle = expression(paste(Geno, italic("vs"), Geno2)), now what i get is Geno and Geno2 in the subtitle instead of its real value by the function

Comment: You are right, I found a working solution and updated my answer. Including a demo.

Comment: Thanks ☺️☺️  You saved me lots of typing...